# wordpress site works, but can not access via wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

(site--.com/wp-admin) not working?

A friend has a wp site that needs some changes, however even though the site works he can not gain access via the wp-admin.

browser shows http error 500, not super helpful.

I have control panel access but not sure if this helps.

Current host is hard to reach and it possible the site has not been updated in quite a while?

Comment: Please refer to this link [http://webcraft.tools/fixing-the-500-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/] may it will be helpful

Comment: Turn on error logging and check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some plugin is disabling the wp-admin access , just by security reason.

For instance some plugins like Simple Firewall ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-simple-firewall/) has the option to rename the admin access.

Solution:

- Open the FTP folder and rename the plugin that is affecting the wp-admin access. Once the Plugin is disabled, you should be able to access to the admin.

Regards,
Ed.